# Unable to run a PS script from UNC path on a remote server

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the following PS command from server A on server B (10.11.12.13) which is supposed to run a PS script locally but from a UNC path. So I have:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.11.12.13 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "\\netshare\PSScript.ps1"}
```

After I enter my credentials it fails with the error:

```
*\\netshare\PSScript.ps1 : The term '\\netshare\Powershell\PSScript.ps1' is not recognized as
+CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (\\netshare\Pow... recognized as :String) [], 
RemoteException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId: NativeCommandError
+PSComputerName: 10.11.12.13*
```

In my command if I replace the unc path with a local path such as C:\files\PSScript.ps1 it runs fine.

The remote server is running PS v4. I've already run the command:
*Set ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted on server B.* I also tried adding -File after Bypass but that also fails with a different error.

How do I get that script to run from server B? Solutions like copying a script to server B first will not work. I also need this to run from the command line (not from a script).

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. There is no reason to invoke `powershell.exe` from within PowerShell. Invoke the script by the call-operator `&`
2. Pay attention to the double-hop issue. If you connect to a remote computer by *network logon* you can't authenticate from within this remote connection to another remote computer (here network share).
3. Use `Invoke-Command -FilePath C:\PSScript.ps1 -ComputerName 10.11.12.13` instead. Thereby you don't have to copy the file to every remote computer in advance.

Comment: I must run the script from a UNC not local drive. The remote server is able to access that share correctly with the same credentials. I invoke powershell.exe because without it -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "\\netshare\PSScript.ps1 will obviously not run.

Comment: The reason I can't run it locally is because admins may make changes to the script on the share so that's also why I need it to run the script from the unc path. Otherwise yes, your command works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working with this:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath \\netshare\PSScript.ps1 -ComputerName 10.11.12.13 -Credential $cred
```

Would still have liked to figure out how to run it inside a ScriptBlock however.

Comment: `-FilePath` is the path to file on your *local* computer, with the credentials you are logged in locally (that's why UNC works too). In regards of your ScriptBlock question, read again my hints 1 and 2. Additionally, make sure you understand the difference between `powershell.exe -File "\\server\script.ps1"` and `powershell.exe -Command "& \\server\script.ps1"`.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I wasn't sure how I was supposed to invoke the script with the & call-operator. I'll have to see what the difference between the two are by trying both your examples. But regarding ScriptBlock, without an example, I don't know if I'll be able to figure out what I was doing wrong originally with my ScriptBlock example. Are you saying it would've worked with: 

ScriptBlock {powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& \\netshare\PSScript.ps1"} ?

Comment: It would have been a step in the right direction. You might have get another error message (Access Denied), still believe you would have get *Access Denied*, that's the double-hop problem I mentioned and depends on whether you performed a network logon or interactive logon.